# What are the values of pointers and variables according to this C code?

Tags: c, pointers

I am confused with pointers....Why is value of `ipp` not 88? It shows garbage if `*ipp=88`? The same can be said with `*ipp`? It also shows garbage, why is that?

Could you please explain how pointers work in my case? And why value of `*ip1` is 97 (how it follows from the formula `*ip1 * 7 + b`)?

```
int a = 11, b = 20;
int x, y;

int *ip1 = &a;
int *ip2 = &x;

int **ipp = &ip2;

*ip2 = *ip1 * 7 + b;

ip1 = ip2;
ip2 = &y;

**ipp = 88;
*ipp = &b;
```

Comment: Because you changes the address pointed to in the last statment `*ipp = &b;` -- is this a trick question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some code which shows what's going on (in excruciating detail):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a = 11;
    int b = 20;
    int x = -1;
    int y = -1;
    int *ip1 = &a;
    int *ip2 = &x;
    int **ipp = &ip2;

    printf("Addresses:\n");
    printf("   &a = %p\n", (void *)&a);
    printf("   &b = %p\n", (void *)&b);
    printf("   &x = %p\n", (void *)&x);
    printf("   &y = %p\n", (void *)&y);
    printf(" &ip1 = %p\n", (void *)&ip1);
    printf(" &ip2 = %p\n", (void *)&ip2);
    putchar('\n');
    printf("%3s  %3s  %3s  %3s  %14s  %14s  %14s  %4s  %4s  %5s\n",
           "a", "b", "x", "y", "ip1", "ip2", "ipp", "*ip1", "*ip2", "**ipp");
    printf("%3d  %3d  %3d  %3d  %14p  %14p  %14p  %4d  %4d  %5d\n",
           a, b, x, y, (void *)ip1, (void *)ip2, (void *)ipp, *ip1, *ip2, **ipp);

    *ip2 = *ip1 * 7 + b;
    printf("%3d  %3d  %3d  %3d  %14p  %14p  %14p  %4d  %4d  %5d\n",
           a, b, x, y, (void *)ip1, (void *)ip2, (void *)ipp, *ip1, *ip2, **ipp);

    ip1 = ip2;
    printf("%3d  %3d  %3d  %3d  %14p  %14p  %14p  %4d  %4d  %5d\n",
           a, b, x, y, (void *)ip1, (void *)ip2, (void *)ipp, *ip1, *ip2, **ipp);

    ip2 = &y;
    printf("%3d  %3d  %3d  %3d  %14p  %14p  %14p  %4d  %4d  %5d\n",
           a, b, x, y, (void *)ip1, (void *)ip2, (void *)ipp, *ip1, *ip2, **ipp);

    **ipp = 88;
    printf("%3d  %3d  %3d  %3d  %14p  %14p  %14p  %4d  %4d  %5d\n",
           a, b, x, y, (void *)ip1, (void *)ip2, (void *)ipp, *ip1, *ip2, **ipp);

    *ipp = &b;
    printf("%3d  %3d  %3d  %3d  %14p  %14p  %14p  %4d  %4d  %5d\n",
           a, b, x, y, (void *)ip1, (void *)ip2, (void *)ipp, *ip1, *ip2, **ipp);

    return 0;
}
```

It simply prints the addresses of all the variables except `ipp` — it's address is never used by any expression in the code.  It then prints the values of each of the plain integers, each of the pointers, and the various dereferenced pointers.

#### Sample output

```
Addresses:
   &a = 0x7fff5bacd4f0
   &b = 0x7fff5bacd4f4
   &x = 0x7fff5bacd4f8
   &y = 0x7fff5bacd4fc
 &ip1 = 0x7fff5bacd500
 &ip2 = 0x7fff5bacd508

  a    b    x    y             ip1             ip2             ipp  *ip1  *ip2  **ipp
 11   20   -1   -1  0x7fff5bacd4f0  0x7fff5bacd4f8  0x7fff5bacd508    11    -1     -1
 11   20   97   -1  0x7fff5bacd4f0  0x7fff5bacd4f8  0x7fff5bacd508    11    97     97
 11   20   97   -1  0x7fff5bacd4f8  0x7fff5bacd4f8  0x7fff5bacd508    97    97     97
 11   20   97   -1  0x7fff5bacd4f8  0x7fff5bacd4fc  0x7fff5bacd508    97    -1     -1
 11   20   97   88  0x7fff5bacd4f8  0x7fff5bacd4fc  0x7fff5bacd508    97    88     88
 11   20   97   88  0x7fff5bacd4f8  0x7fff5bacd4f4  0x7fff5bacd508    97    20     20
```

Make sure you understand what you see — it isn't hard to connect the dots when all the data is present like that.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what this does:

```
int a = 11, b = 20;
int x, y;

int *ip1 = &a;
int *ip2 = &x;

int **ipp = &ip2;
```

At this point a is 11, b is 20, ip1 is &a, ip2 is &x, ipp is &ip2

```
*ip2 = *ip1 * 7 + b;
```

Now x is 97, i.e. 11*7 + 20

```
ip1 = ip2;
ip2 = &y;
```

Now ip1 is &x, ip2 is &y

```
**ipp = 88;
*ipp = &b;
```

Now y is 88, ip2 is &b